# How to determine the url of my mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I am connecting to my MySQL db from my java client and am catching a connection timedout error when instantiating my connection variable. I'm presuming my connection string is incorrect. The java client and MySQL are on same machine.

My mysql db was installed as part of WAMP, i see in its ini file that the port is 3306. i have tried localhost, 127.0.0.1 and my ip i get back from ipconfig with all connection timeout. I cant see in phpMyAdmin any ip but maybe iv missed something there. Perhaps 3306 needs opening even though java client and mySql are on same server.

How can i determine mysql ip and port and if it is open or not?

My code

```
private Connection conn;
private Statement statement;
private ResultSet resultset;

public DbConnect(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.x.x.xxx:3306/pk","root","");
    }       catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'
```

will show you the hostname of the MySQL server which you can easily resolve to its IP address.

You can find details about this in MySQL's manual: 12.4.5.41. SHOW VARIABLES Syntax and 5.1.4. Server System Variables

To check the Port number: 
On which Mysql is running you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
    +---------------+-------+
    | Variable_name | Value |
    +---------------+-------+
    | port          | 3306  |
    +---------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the port number on which MySQL is running.

Comment: fantatsic, thks very much

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a combo of an obvious thing and eclipse not behaving. I had to open the port 3306 on my server and Eclipse wasnt saving my changes so subsequent testing was confused.